# Copy paste the value from one cell to another based on condition using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-services, vba, excel-web-access-webpart

Below are my steps that I need to perform in excel. and I wanted to automate this as & when I run Macro :)

Background : I have already imported one sheet from another workbook and recorded the Lookup and Match formula.

Now what I wanted is :

- Wanted to Copy the value from B1 cell and Paste it to C1 only if the Cell value is Not equals to True (basically am replacing the value which is False from B1 cell to C1 Cell) and then Need to highlight it in Orange colour.

Once the above mentioned task is performed, have to convert the formula to Value and delete the B1 cell.

Is it possible to automate using VBA..

My final workbook should look like, all the False value should be replaced with the updated data and need to be highlighted in Orange (True value shld remain the same).